# Strange Exception in MVC with Url.Action

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

We're getting an exception when calling a function and I don't understand why.
The exception is:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Value does not fall within the expected range.

It's about the two parameters to Instance.Initialize. The exception occurs when Url.Action is used as expression in the argument list.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RestartWorkspace()
    {
        string loadStatus = Url.Action("LoadStatusBar", "Home");
        string noGateway = Url.Action("NoGateway", "NormalMode");

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>  {
                ServiceLayer.WorkSpace.Instance.Initialize(
                    Url.Action("LoadStatusBar", "Home"),
                    Url.Action("NoGateway", "NormalMode"));
        });
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

When changing it to this the exception dissappears

```
string loadStatus = Url.Action("LoadStatusBar", "Home");
string noGateway = Url.Action("NoGateway", "NormalMode");

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>  {
        ServiceLayer.WorkSpace.Instance.Initialize(
        loadStatus,
        noGateway);
});
```

I'd like to understand why the exception is thrown on the first example.
Url.Action can't be used inside a Task or something?

Comment: Could you please show the where this comes from => `ServiceLayer.WorkSpace.Instance.Initialize(...)` ?

Comment: might be any issue in `ServiceLayer.WorkSpace.Instance.Initialize(...)` method ?

Comment: initialize is never entered and Instance is just a singleton where the single instance is long ago instantiated